# how to use url pathname as upstream hash in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server with config to use queryparam as upstream hash. Url looks like below

```
http://www.my-server.com/xyz/WXYZ?abc=123
```

And configuration as below

```
upstream test {
    hash $arg_abc;
    ....
}
```

is there any possibility to use `WXYZ` part of URL as upstream hash?

`WXYZ` is dynamic value and `xyz` is always same and will be there.

this is what I tried,

```
location ~ ^/xyz/(.).*$ {
   hash $1
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The deployment guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/) explicitly said it's possible:

> The generic hash method: the server to which a request is sent is
>   determined from a user-defined key which may be a text, variable, or
>   their combination. For example, the key may be a source IP and port,
>   or URI:

```
upstream backend {
    hash $request_uri consistent;

    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;
}
```

The hash key is **$request_uri** which can be replaced with **$arg_your_key** but not sure is works with upstream block, however it should work as proxy_pass value:

```
location /xyz {
  proxy_pass http://localhost/$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

Not sure of requirements but if you need to use certain backend based on argument **$arg_abc** you need map function, like [here](http://syshero.org/post/114804017957/using-map-for-upstream-configuration-on-nginx):

```
map $arg_abc $backend_server {
 default  'serverdefault.domain.com:80';
 123 'server1.domain.com:80';
 234 'server2.domain.com:80';
 345 'server3.domain.com:80';
}

server {
 location / {
  proxy_pass http://$backend_server;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you have a look at my case here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950567/compose-url-address-on-the-location-with-the-server-ip-address-using-upstream-on

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as per the documentation for [`hash`](http://nginx.org/r/hash), you can only use it in the `upstream` context, so what you've tried won't work indeed.

However, why exactly do you need to use only a certain path from your URI, instead of the whole thing, if those other parts stay the same anyways?  I think the idea is that the whole string is supposed to be further hashed anyways, so, even if all your URLs start the same, the hash function is still supposed to distribute everything evenly.  So, you can most likely just use `$request_uri` or `$uri` as your hash.

Alternatively, if you still want to do it your way, you might try to use named pattern matching in your `location` (`location ~ ^/xyz/(?<varForHash>.).*$ {…`), and then use the variables from such matches (`$varForHash`) as your `hash` (you could probably even use `$1` from your example, too, just in the proper context — `upstream`).

Comment: Can you post some code for second way. I am bit confused here on what I am doing wrong as per your second example

Comment: you're having `hash` directive within `location`, whereas it should be within the `upstream` context; just move it from `location` to `upstream`, which might work; but even if it does, it would be a much better idea to use "named captures" as per above.

Answer (score 2):

I got similar task and I solved it. 
I created upstream.conf and added it to the nginx.conf.
The upstream.conf content is below:

```
map $uri $myvar{
    default $uri;
    # pattern "Method1" + "/" + GUID + "/" + target parameter + "/" + HASH;
    "~*/Method1/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$" $2;
    # pattern "Method2" + "/" + GUID + "/" + target parameter;
    "~*/Method2/(.*)/(.*)$" $2;
}


upstream backend {
    hash $myvar consistent;
    server s1:80;
    server s2:80;
}
```