# Compose URL address on the location with the server IP address using upstream on Nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have this situation where a have lots of API´s running on different machines on different ports using Tomcat.
I can create the upstream with those IP addresses but how to add the other part of the URL to the upstream when setting the proxy_pass?

The upstream:

```
upstream login_api_stream {
   least_conn; 
   server 10.2.54.8:8185;
   server 10.2.54.8:8285;
   server 10.2.54.8:8385;
   server 10.2.54.9:8085 backup;
}
```

Then I create the location inside http:

```
location /login-api/ {
    add_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    # I have to add "login-api/auth" on the upstream
    proxy_pass http://login_api_stream/login-api/auth;
}
```

As you can see I must add this "login-api/auth" because the real URL address on the redirected address is:
http://10.2.54.8:8185/login-api/auth

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I ended up with this solution:

The upstream (important to notice, you cannot use this sign _ in the name of the upstream):

```
upstream newlogin {
   least_conn; 
   server 10.2.54.8:8085;
   server 10.2.54.8:8285;
   server 10.2.54.8:8185;
   server 10.2.54.9:8085 backup;
}
```

The location:

```
location ~ ^/login-api/auth/ {
    add_header Host $host;
    add_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_pass http://newlogin$uri$is_args$args;
}
```

And then in browser I call:

```
http://MyNginxDomain/login-api/auth/
```